# Math quiz from a book

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

A student took some exams. The arithmetical average of his grades is 25. He takes another exam today and he gets a 30, so the arithmetical average of his grades becomes 26. How many exams did he take, including today’s one?

Edit: I know how to solve this, it’s from a book, I found it interesting and I posted it for you!

Comment: sorry to close your question! Unfortunately we're quite strict around here about puzzles being _puzzles_ rather than _routine mathematics problems_; this one is basically a matter of writing down an equation and solving it. Take a look at xnor's answer to the meta question linked in the close message, which lays out the key distinction very nicely.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan don’t worry, I didn’t know. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> 5

Reason:

> Let he gave n exams earlier
>  Then total initial total=25n
>  So new average=(25n+30)/(n+1)=26
>  Solving we get n=4, so he gave 
>  n+1=5 exams including today's

Comment: Almost right...

Comment: This is correct; the question asks how many exams were taken, _including today's_.

Comment: rot13: Lbh pbhyq nyfb tb nobhg guvf ol fnlvat gur qvssrerapr bs 5 rknz cbvagf tvirf n 1 cbvag nirentr vapernfr, fb 5/1 = ahzore bs rknzf. Unys n cbvag jbhyq or 5/0.5 = 10 rknzf, rgp.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin exactly, be careful.

Comment: Just to let you know, it was 4

Answer (score 2):

This question might be better fit on the [***Math Stack Exchange***](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but I will answer this anyway :)

---

We get

> $$\frac{x+30}{y}=26$$ $$\frac{x}{y}=25$$ where $x$ is the total of his exams' results excluding today's exam, and $y$ is the number of exams.

We know that

> $$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{30}{y}=25+\frac{30}{y}=26$$

Therefore

> $$\frac{30}{y}=1$$

so

> $$y=30$$

That's how many exams he took, including today's one.

Comment: I know the solution, I found it challenging and I wanted to post it

Comment: By the way it’s wrong, try again!

Comment: @Marybnq it is? Hmm....

Comment: Yes, try solving it keeping in mind the arithmetical average rule

Comment: That second fraction should be x / (y-1) as the previous average would not include today's exam

Comment: @Marybnq well, arithmetical average is the mean $m$ where $m=\frac 1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$. I simply applied this rule, such that $x_i$ represents his grades for each exam, respectively, and $n=26$ where $x_{26}=30$.